# Jquery Scroll full screen background div

Tags: jquery

I am using this function which works ok for one screen size.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > 1400) {
       jQuery('.mymenu').addClass('menu-invert');
    } else {
       jQuery('.mymenu').removeClass('menu-invert');
    }
});
```

The problem is that on the top of each page, I have a full screen background div which is set in my css as follows:

```
#fullimg {height: 100vh;}
```

I need to somehow calculate for all screen sizes that the user has fully scrolled after the `#fullimg` before adding/removing the new class 'menu-invert' as seen above.

Comment: Change `1400` to a calculated height relevant to the screen size, eg. `$(window).height()`, or some other value which is relevant for your use case. Without more specific details in the question - or a working example - it's hard to provide any more accurate details.

Comment: ok thanks for this but not sure how else to explain it - I have a full screen background cover image and this is the same case for all screen sizes.. the user needs to scroll past this cover image for the change to happen

Comment: I suppose $(window).height(); should do the trick so I will just try that